# Dynamic jQuery unslider populated from Ajax not clearing children in <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface, unslider

I have this unslider which display tweets polled from some sources via Ajax which refreshes every 8 sec. The Unslider works fine for the first time but subsequently when new ajax queries are fired, it is supposed to clear the first

tags and repopulate with new one. For some reason, it doesn't clear out the old tags and instead appends the new tags to the old.
Here are the screenshots:

[image: On the First Ajax Request, everything looks fine:]

[image: This is how it looks when subsequent requests are fired]

[image: After Inspecting we can see that it didn't clear the <ul> and instead appended the new <li> to the <ul>]

```js
var flag = false;
(function setTweets() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../tweets/get_latest_tweets",
    success: function(data) {
      //clear all children first
      $('#tweets-list').children().remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('<li>' + data[i].text + '<div class="card-footer bg-twitter"><div class="card-profile-image"><img src="' + data[i].pic + '" class="rounded-circle img-border box-shadow-1" alt="Card Image"></div>' +
          '<footer class="blockquote-footer bg-twitter white"><strong>@' + data[i].screen_name + '</strong></footer></div></li>').appendTo($('#tweets-list'))
      }

      if (!flag) {
        $('#tweet-slider').unslider({ //initialize unslider only once
          autoplay: true,
          arrows: true,
          speed: 1000,
          delay: 7000,
        });
        flag = true;
      }


    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }).then(function() {
    setTimeout(setTweets, 8000); //Todo: Check how to do this async (dynamic adding of points)
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card bg-twitter white">
  <div class="card-content p-2">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="text-center mb-1">
        <i class="ft-twitter font-large-3"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="tweet-slider" id="tweet-slider">
        <ul id='tweets-list' class="text-center">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach() instead.

According to this, you are removing # tweets-list as an element, I think if you use .empty () you will clean it

uses `$('#tweets-list').empty();`

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that partially solved the issue. Now, it's not appending the additional <li> but still the unslider remains the same. Maybe its an issue with unslider. I think we can't change it after initialization or something. Not sure

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the unslider website and it says that if you delete or add slides you should use the method `slider.unslider('calculateSlides');`

```
var flag = false;
(function setTweets() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../tweets/get_latest_tweets",
    success: function(data) {
      //clear all children first
      $('#tweets-list').children().remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('<li>' + data[i].text + '<div class="card-footer bg-twitter"><div class="card-profile-image"><img src="' + data[i].pic + '" class="rounded-circle img-border box-shadow-1" alt="Card Image"></div>' +
          '<footer class="blockquote-footer bg-twitter white"><strong>@' + data[i].screen_name + '</strong></footer></div></li>').appendTo($('#tweets-list'))
      }

      if (!flag) {
        $('#tweet-slider').unslider('calculateSlides');
        flag = true;
      }


    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }).then(function() {
    setTimeout(setTweets, 8000); //Todo: Check how to do this async (dynamic adding of points)
  });
})();
```

apparently there is no need to reinitialize the unslider, try it but, you restart it

Comment: Yeah. I saw that too. It didn't work, unfortunately. Still same issue